# Add rollover effect to dynamic movieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, rollover

I am not sure how I can replace one movie clip with another when I click on the first one. Below is my code that shows me loading the first movieClip and adding it to the stage and assigning a OnClick listener.

```
thumbs_button.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideoButton);

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++) {
        var playButton_url = "play_now.png";
        var playButton_loader = new Loader();
        playButton_loader.name = i;
        playButton_loader.load (new URLRequest(root_path + playButton_url));
        playButton_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, playButtonLoaded);
}

    function playVideoButton (e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("Button " + e.target);
        //thumbs_button.removeChild(e.target);
        var video_url = root_path +  my_videos[e.target.name].@URL;
        my_player.source = video_url;



    }

function playButtonLoaded (e:Event):void {
    var my_playButton:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    thumbs_button.addChild (my_playButton);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using a for loop to load an image ("play_now.png") multiple times in one movieclip (thumbs_button), but here's how you remove the loaded image:

```
var playButton_url = "play_now.png";
var playButton_loader = new Loader();

playButton_loader.name = "play_now";
playButton_loader.load (new URLRequest(root_path + playButton_url));

thumbs_button.addChild(playButton_loader);

function playVideoButton (e:MouseEvent)
{
    thumbs_button.removeChild(thumbs_button.getChildByName("play_now"));
}
```